# Best format for News Stand App content distribution

Tags: newsstand-kit

I am creating a News Stand application, I am just confused on which format to select: PDF or ePub or HTML5.

I am more inclined to HTML5 - are there any good samples on how to package an issue with HTML5 for distribution as issues in my News Stand app (I believe for HTML5 - I just need to load the Index/ToC page in WebView that way the rest pages are rendered automatically from the HTMLs itself).

Looking forward to your suggestions and advice.

Comment: did you come to a conclusion on this? what method did you pursue?